# Microsoft Access condense multiple lines in a table - Clarification

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have two tables. In one table I have my clients name and general information. In the other related table, I have the properties that they own or operate.

I am attempting to produce a concatenated list of properties in the same recordset with the client's name. I was attempting to apply the `GetList` function but I can't seem to work out the accompanying query that applies the function.

I am sure it a simple misunderstanding, but I have been unable to figure out the exact way to make it work. I have `Fulfillment_Client_Table.ClientMasterNumber` which I am trying mate up with `FulfillmentResortTable.ResortName` showing the multiple returns of `ResortNames` on a single row with `ClientMasterNumber`.

The Function I am using is:

```vb
Public Function GetList(SQL As String _
                            , Optional ColumnDelimeter As String = ", " _
                            , Optional RowDelimeter As String = vbCrLf) As String
'PURPOSE: to return a combined string from the passed query
'ARGS:
'   1. SQL is a valid Select statement
'   2. ColumnDelimiter is the character(s) that separate each column
'   3. RowDelimiter is the character(s) that separate each row
'RETURN VAL: Concatenated list
'DESIGN NOTES:
'EXAMPLE CALL: =GetList("Select Col1,Col2 From Table1 Where Table1.Key = " & OuterTable.Key)

Const PROCNAME = "GetList"
Const adClipString = 2
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sResult As String

On Error GoTo ProcErr

Set oConn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set oRS = oConn.Execute(SQL)

sResult = oRS.GetString(adClipString, -1, ColumnDelimeter, RowDelimeter)

If Right(sResult, Len(RowDelimeter)) = RowDelimeter Then
    sResult = Mid$(sResult, 1, Len(sResult) - Len(RowDelimeter))
End If

GetList = sResult
oRS.Close
oConn.Close

CleanUp:
    Set oRS = Nothing
    Set oConn = Nothing

Exit Function
ProcErr:
    ' insert error handler
    Resume CleanUp

End Function
```

and different variations of this

```sql
SELECT Fulfillment_Client_Table.ClientMasterNumber, 
       GetList((SELECT ResortName FROM FulfillmentResortTable As T1
                WHERE T1.ClientMasterNumber = [Fulfillment_Client_Table].[ClientMasterNumber]) as ResortName)
FROM Fulfillment_Client_Table
```

Not sure what I do not understand?

Answer (score 0):

As the very inline comment example call shows:

```vb
'EXAMPLE CALL: =GetList("Select Col1,Col2 From Table1 Where Table1.Key = " & OuterTable.Key)
```

You need to pass a quoted string SQL statement and not an actual subquery:

```sql
SELECT f.ClientMasterNumber, 
       GetList("SELECT ResortName FROM FulfillmentResortTable As sub WHERE sub.ClientMasterNumber = " & f.[ClientMasterNumber]) as ResortName
FROM Fulfillment_Client_Table f
```